# Autonumber in MS access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an issue with my access form. When I delete a record the auto number takes away that number also.
For example

```
1 is cheese pizza.
2 is vegie pizza.
3 is sausage pizza.
```

when I delete 2 and try to enter a new pizza i get.

```
1 is cheese pizza.
3 is sausage pizza.
4 is chicken pizza.
```

Is there a way to fix this to work without creating a new table?

Answer (score 2):

This is how autonumbers work. If you want consecutive numbers, do not rely on an autonumber field, generate your own numbers.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way, it will delete number of autonumber column anyway.
use ordinary number field instead and insert/update your numbers in it manually.